# How can I expand my grid-column-start to grid-column-end to take exactly half of the current grid size

Tags: html, css, reactjs

In this codepen I included my code [here](https://codepen.io/lmgcrew/pen/PoKBaXX). What I want to achieve is that boxes `8` and `9` take up exactly half of the current grid size width-wise. So boxes `8` and `9` should be together with the whole width of the grid and meet in the middle right below box `3`. I am writing this in react but this shouldn't be important for the purpose of what I am doing.

```js
const Grid = () => {
  return ( <
    div class = 'container' >
    <
    div class = 'cell cell-1' > 1. < /div> <
    div class = 'cell cell-2' > 2. < /div> <
    div class = 'cell cell-3' > 3. < /div> <
    div class = 'cell cell-4' > 4. < /div> <
    div class = 'cell cell-5' > 5. < /div> <
    div class = 'cell cell-6' > 6. < /div> <
    div class = 'cell cell-7' > 7. < /div> <
    div class = 'cell cell-8' > 8. < /div> <
    div class = 'cell cell-9' > 9. < /div> < /
    div >
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return ( <
    div >
    <
    Grid / >
    <
    /div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render( <
  React.StrictMode >
  <
  App / >
  <
  /React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.container {
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 2rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 3px;
}

.cell {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4rem;
}

.cell-1 {
  background: deepskyblue;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.cell-2 {
  background: orange;
}

.cell-3 {
  background: royalblue;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column-start: 3;
}

.cell-4 {
  background: gold;
}

.cell-5 {
  background: blueviolet;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column-start: 5;
}

.cell-6 {
  background: limegreen;
}

.cell-7 {
  background: coral;
}

.cell-8 {
  background: lightseagreen;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

.cell-9 {
  background: maroon;
  grid-row-start: 3;
}

.cell-10 {
  background: mediumaquamarine;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the following Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/moshiuramit/pen/ExvpdKV)

I have added a width attribute along with grid-column-end. It will work without changing the html structure.

```
.cell-8 {
  background: lightseagreen;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  width: 104.8%;
  left: 0;
  item-self: flex-end;
}

.cell-9 {
  background: maroon;
  width: 104.8%;
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 6;
  justify-self: flex-end;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this it works as well. I will be keeping the other one only cause I feel like it's more intuitive but knowing different ways to achieve the same thing is great.

Comment: You are Welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Just add grid-column-end in box 8 and 9.

```
.cell-8 {
  background: lightseagreen;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}

.cell-9 {
    background: maroon;
    grid-row-start: 3;
    grid-column-start: 4;
    grid-column-end: 6;
}
```

**Updated:**

```
.container {
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 2rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 3px;
}

.cell {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4rem;
}

.cell-1 {
  background: deepskyblue;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.cell-2 {
  background: orange;
}

.cell-3 {
  background: royalblue;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 5;
}

.cell-4 {
  background: gold;
}

.cell-5 {
  background: blueviolet;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column-start: 5;
}

.cell-6 {
  background: limegreen;
}

.cell-7 {
  background: coral;
}

.cell-8 {
  background: lightseagreen;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-column-start: 1; 
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  
}

.cell-9 {
  background: maroon;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 7
}

.cell-10 {
  background: mediumaquamarine;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-column-start: 5;
  grid-column-end: 6;
}
```

**Another Solution**

Separate box 8 and 9 to another div.
Check out [here](https://codepen.io/Pusoy/pen/RwZBByz)

Comment: Thanks. This does not work though. I want `8` and `9` to meet in the middle of box `3`. Your solution is all I was able to achieve before which is box `8` taking up all of box `3` and `9` taking up the rest

Comment: So, basically I was hoping for box `8` and box `9` to take up exactly half of the current grid size each.

Comment: It is because you have only 5 columns in your grid, in order to achieve that goal it must be divisible by 2.

Comment: Check the updated css.

Comment: Thanks again. It's my fault and I should have been more clear in my post. I did think of this solution but I wanted each column to take the same amount of space width-wise besides boxes `8` and `9` which are aligned the way they should be with the current solution you provided. However, box `3` is not the same width as boxes `1`, `2`, `6`, `5`, `4`, or `7`.

Comment: I was thinking I can maybe achieve this by using `pixels` or `rem` or something of that nature but I tried and failed unfortunately. Not sure if you have any ideas for this?

Comment: I dont think so it is possible because you are using grid.

Comment: Just try to separate box 8 and 9 to a different div and use grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr

Comment: Ah, okay. Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you!

Comment: Check out Another Solution in my comment it should solve your problem.

Comment: I actually got it but yes this works. Thanks!!